# flag start point and end point of streaming video node.js

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, video-streaming, html5-video

I'm trying to write a nodejs website for streaming html5 video (webm, mp4). But don't know how to know when user finished viewing video. That mean, we need a start point (the point that user start to view video), and an end point(the point that user finished to view video). And we can know how many percents that they are viewed the video.
The video are located at our server.

Answer (score 0):

The video HTML element (which is a subclass of MediaElement) has currentTime and duration properties that you can look at in JavaScript, and also a bunch of events you can listen for, like onplay, onplaying, onpause, ontimeupdate, etc.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement